# Rails Minitest Has Many And Belongs To Model Test ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fixtures

When I try to run minitest with simpleCov, I want the join table model `UserMessages` to be covered.

I have setup fixture, to run test and keep getting an `ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey` error. This is expected since I don't have a primary key on the UserMessage table.

Is there a way to bypass this error and also have coverage on the UserMessage model?

MODELS:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :messages, join_table "users_messages"
end

class Message < ApplicaitonRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: "users_messages"
end

class UserMessage <ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "users_messsages"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :messages
end
```

FIXTURES:

User:

```
default:
  name: test
```

Message:

```
default:
  message: hello world!
  users:
   - default
```

UserMessage:

```
default:
  user: default
  message: default
```

TEST:

```rb
require "test_helpers"
class UserMessageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 def setup
  @user_message = user_message(:default) # The error happens here: ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey:\ 
                                         # Unknown primary key for table users_messages in model \      
                                         # UserMessage
 end

 test "is valid" do
  assert @user_message.valid?, "Should be valid"
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized how bad this is.

I could just not use the fixture to fix the problem.

```rb
require "test_helper"
UserMessageTest < AcitveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
   @user_message = UserMessage.new(user_id: User.first.id,
                                   message_id: Message.first.id)

  end

  test "could save successfully" do
   assert @user_message.save
  end
end
```

And the test passes!